# É certo dizer "fui para a escola, mais, fui para casa primeiro"?

Tags: gramática

Podemos dizer "fui para a escola, mais, fui para casa primeiro", no sentido de que fui para a escola, mas tenho mais uma coisa para dizer, acrescentando, "mais", e essa coisa "fui para casa primeiro", como dizemos semelhantemente "fui para a escola, e mais, ainda fui para casa primeiro"?

Comment: Eu olho para a tua frase e interpreto o *mais* como ’mais ainda, além disso’ ou o ’e mais’ do teu último exemplo. Mas ajudaria se desses um exemplo com contexto (porque creio que as duas respostas abaixo interpretaram mal a tua intenção). O que queres dizer é algo como: "Disseste que não tinhas tempo para falar comigo, que te ias logo embora, mas afinal ficaste lá o dia todo." "Não fiquei, não; fui para a escola; mais, fui para casa primeiro" (não só fui para a escola, como, além disso, até fui para casa antes). É numa coisa deste tipo que está a pensar?

Comment: Renanlinux, poderias desaceitar a minha resposta, por favor, já que ela está errada? Obrigado.

Comment: Parece que você entendeu direito, Jacinto. Mesmo assim devo recusar a resposta, Jacinto e Schilive? Confirmem para mim, por favor; talvez vocês tenham entendido algo que não entendi.

Comment: Para mim, a resposta do Schilive não está correta. Nomeadamente, na tua frase as vírgulas são necessárias. No lugar da primeira eu até poria um ponto final ou ponto e vírgula: "Fui para a escola; mais, fui para casa primeiro". O @Schilive pode corrigir a resposta. Eu ainda te escrevo uma resposta também, mas preciso de tempo para encontrar exemplos semelhantes na literatura.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim, esse uso de *mais* está correto. Eu recomendo é substituir a vírgula antes de *mais* por ponto final ou ponto e vírgula; em vez da vírgula depois de *mais* podes também usar dois pontos, como ilustro a seguir (inventei mais algum contexto para se compreender melhor):

> Ana — Disseste que não ficavas na praia muito mais tempo, mas afinal disseram-me que ficaste lá o dia todo.
> Bruno — Não fiquei, não. À tarde fui para a escola. **Mais:** fui para casa primeiro

Dois exemplos deste uso que eu encontrei no Google Books. O primeiro acerca da inadequação das cuecas novas:

> [As mulheres] esquecem-se que, ao contrário dos soutiens, as cuecas não têm em conta o tamanho do sexo e acessórios. **Mais:** Também, ao contrário das mamas (pelo menos das que conheço) os nossos tomates são assimétricos, e isso, minhas amigas, não é considerado pelos fabricantes.
> [Luis Luz, *Vida de Casado*](https://books.google.pt/books?id=G36YAgAAQBAJ&pg=PT117&dq=%22mais%20tamb%C3%A9m%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwisyejP0sHuAhVjAmMBHTbrBmo4FBDoATACegQIBRAC#v=onepage&q=%22mais%20tamb%C3%A9m%22&f=false)

Estoutro é a propósito duma cooperativa que tinha uma regra de repartição de proveitos que promovia o crescimento mas beneficiava o sócios jovens mais do que os antigos:

> Os sócios mais antigos admitem que esse crescimento deve-se ao trabalho dos mais jovens. Além disso, como a intenção era estabelecer um vínculo entre capital e trabalho, eles aceitaram a regra. Seria uma espécie de tributo ao trabalho dos mais jovens, pois eles teriam mais ímpeto, mais envolvimento, mais motivação. **Mais:** se não há crescimento real, não muda nada, ninguém ganha.
> [Renato Bernhoeft e Joaquim Castanheira, *Manual de Sobrevivência para Sócios e Herdeiros*, 1995](https://books.google.pt/books?id=QrOGbXi26VkC&pg=PA116&lpg=PA116&dq=%22Mais:%20se%20n%C3%A3o%20h%C3%A1%20crescimento%20real%22&source=bl&ots=wZPFTgj-sf&sig=ACfU3U2qp8IptqftK5mDYapRKQH9soeYgA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjOi6rQ3cHuAhXZEcAKHWypA4wQ6AEwAHoECAEQAg#v=onepage&q=%22Mais%3A%20se%20n%C3%A3o%20h%C3%A1%20crescimento%20real%22&f=false)

No exemplo da pergunta, como nestes dois últimos exemplos, na fala há uma pausa clara antes do *mais*, o que indica o fim da frase anterior e que na escrita deve ser indicado por ponto final ou, no mínimo, ponto e vírgula. A seguir ao *mais* há também uma pausa na fala, que deve ser indicada por vírgula ou dois pontos. Os dois pontos justificam-se, porque a seguir vem aquilo em que consiste o *mais*. Este *mais* é equivalente a *mais ainda, e mais* e serve para reforçar o que foi dito antes.

Answer (score -1):

Nesse caso, o problema é ortográfico.
Se sua intenção é dizer "fui para escola, só que antes fui para casa", o erro está em "MAIS", que nesse caso tem de ser escrito "MAS".
MAS é uma preposição e MAIS é um substantivo com a intenção de adicionar algo.
Para que uma frase não fique deselegante, você pode utilizar o sinônimo de MAS, que é PORÉM.

Exemplo:

- Fui fazer algumas contas MAS chegou um amigo e me confundiu MAIS"

Trocando:

- Fui fazer algumas contas, PORÉM chegou um amigo e me confundiu MAIS".

Em inglês, MAIS é usado bastante usado como MORE e MAS é para algo como BUT.

Comment: O sentido verdadeiro da frase é de acrescentação mesmo. A outra resposta já disse que está certo utilizar "mais", mas você terá que ler novamente para tentar entender o motivo. Dê atenção à vírgula que muda o sentido. Se fosse usado "mas", não teria vírgula.